# Python - Calling methods inside a class, from inside a class

Tags: python

I am currently trying to create a little piece of code that will return a full deck of cards. I am trying to call the createDeck() method from within the **init**() method. For some reason there is an error showing up. Can anyone explain a solution around this, or why it is not working? I tried removing the class, and only having the methods, and it worked perfectly.

```
class FullDeck():
    '''
    Returns a full 52 card deck
    '''
    names = ('Ace','One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight',
                'Nine','Ten','Jack','Queen','King')     
    suits = ('Hearts','Spades','Clubs','Diamonds')
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = createDeck()

    def createDeck(self):
        currentDeck = []
        for it1 in FullDeck.names:
            for it2 in FullDeck.suits:
                currentDeck.append(it1 + ' of ' + it2)
        return currentDeck
```

Comment: What error is showing up? Also, can you include the code where you call this?

Comment: Use `self.deck = self.createDeck()`.

Comment: Thanks so much @ChrisP! Didn't realize you needed self on both of these.

Comment: Others have answered your question; but your method can be simplified to `def createDeck(self): return ['{} of {}'.format(i, j) for i in FullDeck.suits for j in FullDeck.names]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike other languages, Python classes don't have an implicit reference to themselves. You must explicitly use a reference if you want to call any methods on the same object.

```
self.deck = self.createDeck()
```

Also note that since the method is only used to create the attribute on the object, it should perform that operation itself.

```
def __init__(self):
     ...
    self.createDeck()

def createDeck(self):
    currentDeck = []
         ...
    self.deck = currentDeck
```

Comment: I think you mean `self.createDeck()` in line 3

Answer (score 0):

As one of the comments suggested, you need to use

```
def __init__(self):
    self.deck = self.createdeck()
```

to get the result you're looking for.